# Unable to write system console log in MAC os x 10.12 using swift 3

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swift3

I would like to write my applications log under folder /var/log/APPLICATION.log 
My application is written in swift 3 and is using NSLOG for writing log information to console log.

In OS X 10.11 and earlier, I am able to correctly write logs at /var/log/APPLICATION.log location. However the same is not happening in OS X 10.12.

Any Idea why is this happening?